# How To Exit Zend Command Line Prompt

Tags: zend-framework

I am working through the Zend framework tutorial at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/.

Right now I am on the 'Create a Model and Database Table' section, and have followed the tutorial's guidelines for initializing database resources.  In my terminal I entered

> zf configure db-adapter \

then

> adapter=PDO_SQLITE&dbname=APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook.db" \

and then

> production

At this point, I am supposed to receive a message saying that a db configuration for production has been written to my config file.  Instead, the prompt stays open.  I've tried using ":q", ":quit", and "\q" to leave the prompt, but those don't work.  The server that I am working on runs of RHEL5.  I know I can close the terminal and open a new one, but I want to learn how to actually get out of the zend framework command line prompt.  Solutions?

Comment: OK, I think I found the problem as to **why** the command line was hanging;  The input should have been

    zf.sh configure db-adapter **'**adapter=PDO_SQLITE&dbname=APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook.db"**'** production

Looks like I missed a closing quote.  Pete Mitchell has the right answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will exit a prompt.